# How do I keep a BackgroundWorker from blocking the UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my XML editor I want to be able to open multiple files at once using an index file. Obviously, depending on the amount of files, this can take a bit of time and I want to use a progress bar to notify the user that the programm is still loading and doing something. 
From what I have researched the way to keep the UI progress bar updated is using a BackgroundWorker.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tabList = new ObservableCollection<FileTab>();

            tabControl.ItemsSource = tabList;

            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
            backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true; 
        }

(...)

private void OpenProjectButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {
            openingProgressBar.Value = 0;
            openingProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (IndexFile file in indexManager.fileList)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        tabList.Add(new FileTab(file.filePath));
                    }));
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine("-(DoWork)->" + i);
                double percentage = (Convert.ToDouble(i) / Convert.ToDouble(indexManager.fileList.Count)) * 100;
                Console.WriteLine("-(DoWork.percentage)-> "+ percentage);
                backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)percentage);
            }
        }
void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            openingProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            Console.WriteLine("-(ProgressChanged)->" + openingProgressBar.Value);
        }
void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            openingProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            backgroundWorker.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("-(RunWorkerComplete)-> Done");
        }
```

Since I'm accessing the tablist in the DoWork-Method I wrap that call in the Dispathcer.Invoke. In this form the code kind of does what I want. It makes the collapsed progressBar visible and updates it every once in a while. Sadly it doesn't update the percentage after every file loaded. From what I can see in the console, the ProgressChanged execution lags behind the DoWork. From my understanding it is called in every iteration of the loop though. And even if it fires the UI doesn't always respond to that.

So my question is: Am I still blocking the UI thread somehow and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that

> you are do a coupling between UI and BackgroundWorker

The Solution

> return on ReportProgress your FileTab object

```
void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (IndexFile file in indexManager.fileList)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("-(DoWork)->" + i);
        double percentage = (Convert.ToDouble(i) / Convert.ToDouble(indexManager.fileList.Count)) * 100;
        Console.WriteLine("-(DoWork.percentage)-> "+ percentage);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)percentage,new FileTab(file.filePath));
    }
}
```

then add your FileTab object in your `backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged` to the `tabList`

Comment: This worked and now it's so fast I barely need the progress bar anymore... Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me. I'm reporting the current loop `i` and inside the report-event I'm setting this int to a property called `ProgressValue`. This `ProgressValue` is bound to the progressbar as value. My UI is still blocking.

Comment: @C4u so how about just changing that? (i can't see your problem). Do your work in the `DoWork` (all values must be autonom from your UI) and each time you finish a part report it to your UI threat via `ReportProgress` (here you can use UI Values (like your `ProgressValue`) in the end when your all your work is done call `RunWorkerCompleted` if you need to do again something in your UI. I hope this will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the reporting progress operation into the dispatcher's operations:

```
 foreach (IndexFile file in indexManager.fileList)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        tabList.Add(new FileTab(file.filePath));
                        Console.WriteLine("-(DoWork)->" + i);
                        double percentage = (Convert.ToDouble(i) / Convert.ToDouble(indexManager.fileList.Count)) * 100;
                        Console.WriteLine("-(DoWork.percentage)-> "+ percentage);
                        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)percentage);
                    }));
                i++;

            }
```

It's possible that dispatcher runs in another thread...

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to change the behaviour.